# Unity 5 animation triggers (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, animation, unity-game-engine

I am working in unity 5 and I am trying to get an animation to work properly. When the button "Fire1" aka left clicking is pressed, my enemies' health decreased until it reaches zero health.

When the health reaches zero the death animation is supposed to play.

Neither `GetComponent<animation>("Dead")` or `play.animation("Dead")` seem to be working.

I also tried `GetComponent.<animation>("Dead")`.

The first snippet of code doesn't seem to work because of the `<` and `>`. The second snippet doesn't work because `.` and `play` (even though I made a variable for it). Thank you for any help you can provide. My code is

```
#pragma strict

var range: float = 1.8;
var attackInterval: float = 0.7;
var meleeDamage: float = 30;
var GetComponent.<animation>("Dead");
private var nextAttack: float = 0;

function MeleeAttack()
{
    if (Time.time > nextAttack)
    { // only repeat attack after attackInterval
        nextAttack = Time.time + attackInterval;
        // get all colliders whose bounds touch the sphere
        var colls: Collider[] = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 
    range);
        for (var hit : Collider in colls)
        {
            if (hit && hit.tag == "Enemy")
            { // if the object is an enemy...
              // check the actual distance to the melee center
                var dist = Vector3.Magnitude(hit.transform.position - 
    transform.position);
                if (dist <= range)
                { // if inside the range...
                  // apply damage to the hit object
                    hit.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", meleeDamage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        MeleeAttack();
    }
}

var health: float = 100;

function ApplyDamage(damage: float)
{
    if (health > 0)
    { // if enemy still alive (don't kick a dead dog!)
        health -= damage; // apply the damage...
                          // <- enemy can emit some sound here with audio.Play();
        if (health <= 0)
        GetComponent.<animation>("Dead");
        { // if health has gone...
          // enemy dead: destroy it, explode it etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) and [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) from the Unity Docs! In your code `var GetComponent.<animation>("Dead");` is wrong in multible ways. Than in your last function the lines `if(health >= 0)  GetComponent.<animation>("Dead"); { ... }` makes no sence

Comment: Thank you for the links. What might you suggest I do to fix the code?

Comment: See my answer. It is really hard since I don't now much about your project structure and how exactly you connect things. Maybe it would help to see a screenshot of your Inspector in Unity with a better description what and how exactly shall happen

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess since I don't really understand how you are trying to get the Animation.

I'm assuming you want to be able to drag-in an animation in the Editor/Inspector.

And I have to admit I usually use C# and can't promise the code here will be correct for Unityscript. I marked lines where I made changes (`CHANGE`) .. I didn't touch the rest of your code so no warranty it works after copy paste.

Better have a look at the links I provided

```
#pragma strict

var range: float = 1.8;
var attackInterval: float = 0.7;
var meleeDamage: float = 30;

/* 
 * CHANGE 1
 *
 * https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/animation
 * https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html
 */
var deadAnimation : Animation; 

private var nextAttack: float = 0;

/* 
 * CHANGE 2
 * https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html
 * https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/getcomponent
 *
 * if you drag it in via the Inspector you don't need this
 * but if you want to make it private and not drag it in via inspector 
 * than you need to get the component here
 */
function Start(){
    if(!deadAnimation){
        deadAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }
}

function MeleeAttack()
{
  ...
}

function Update()
{
  ...
}

var health: float = 100;

function ApplyDamage(damage: float)
{
    if (health > 0)
    { // if enemy still alive (don't kick a dead dog!)
        health -= damage; // apply the damage...
                          // <- enemy can emit some sound here with audio.Play();
        if (health <= 0)
        { // if health has gone...
          // enemy dead: destroy it, explode it etc.

          /*
           * CHANGE 3
           * https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html
           *
           * I assume at some point you want to play the animtion here
           */
          deadAnimation.Play
        }
    }
}
```